# Querying oauth/userinfo gives UserNotFound

Tags: docusignapi

This is only happening in production, JWT flow.

My end goal is to get the *base_uri*, which is required to make any subsequent API calls. I am following [this guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken#step-4-retrieve-user-account-data), attempting to hit https://account.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo returns this error:

```
{
    "error": "UserNotFound",
    "error_description": "The user is not found in DocuSign",
    "reference_id": "7b974b3a-ee7c-47a0-a204-0b8f39d71811"
}
```

(The user I am impersonating is the admin user, if that makes any difference)

Weird thing is that I can follow the exact same steps in [Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant), and successfully get userinfo.

I could potentially use the Auth Code flow to get the *base_uri* first, then use the JWT flow to impersonate the admin. **BUT** this leads to a very weird issue, when I attempt to get the Access Token, the API returns:

```
{
    "error": "consent_required"
}
```

This error doesn't go away even if I try to obtain consent again, and only goes away if I revoke the consent and restart the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the reference ID you provided, I was able to look up the user in question and have determined the user ID in question is impacted by a known issue: PROV-571. For more information, please see this article: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Empty-UserInfo

To get this resolved, please email go-live@docusign.com and include the following info:

- Is the issue occurring in Demo or Production
- UserID & Email address of impacted user
- Known account IDs for user
- Integration Key used

Comment: Thanks! I'll reach out and see how it goes

Comment: Solved after the bad profile is closed, thanks Drew!

Answer (score 0):

The users in production are different than the user in demo/Dev sandbox.
when using JWT, the request for the token requires you provide (among other things) the userIs for the user. This user has to also grant consent to your app/integration to make API calls on your behalf.
You have to double check two things:

1. The userId that you are passing (it's a GUID) to get the JWT token.
2. That the same user granted consent (in production!) to your application.

For more information check https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

Comment: I was able to fetch userinfo via the Auth Code grant using production values of everything, so I am pretty sure both checks you mentioned are met

Comment: auth code grant does not use a userId to impersonate as part of the process. So that is the difference.

Comment: other differences - RSA keypair (private key) has to be used for JWT, and the consent for JWT has to be obtained separately because JWT doesn't interactively login the user

Comment: Hm, so I was able to get the access token, I thought that meant the RSA key and the JWT was valid?

Comment: you obtained it using the JWT flow? that would mean you used some userId (a GUID) of a user to impersonate. That user must have provided consent already.

Comment: if you are using an SDK, you get get the user/account info using this calls:
            OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = ApiClient.GetUserInfo(authToken.access_token);

Comment: I got the user's GUID from https://admin.docusign.com/edit-user/xxxx, where the xxxx is their GUID

Comment: Using the SDK, it's giving me the same error as before, "The user is not found in DocuSign". The user I am impersonating has a Permission Profile of DS Admin, does that affect things?

Comment: no, it doesn't. it's ok to use any user from DocuSign

Comment: I wonder if you are still making the API calls to demo/Sandbox and not production or maybe you are using the wrong site. What URL are you using to make the call? is it www.docusign.net ? or is it something like na2.docusign.net or eu.docusign.net ?

Comment: actually, see email from Drew. looks like this one is in bad state on our systems, please email him and he'll help fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get userInfo when the token was generated via the Authorization Code Grant, but not when the token was generated by the JWT Grant, then something is wrong with either:

- The JWT Grant flow: wrong user guid, wrong IdP server (should be account.docusign.com), etc
- The userInfo call: wrong server (should be account.docusign.com) or something related.

Comment: In this case it's a known issue with some users in DocuSign. Thanks for the response!